# SQL query having an issue

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi there I'm having an issue with an SQL query, it works but I don't know if it's right (I'm learning to code)..

I've written this statement..

```
SELECT CONCAT(Member_Name, ' ', last_name) AS full_name FROM members ORDER BY last_name DESC, Member_Name DESC
```

It's displaying this:

[image]

Is this right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

Your query looks right.  Just ignore "Tony House" and the results look correct too ;)  Sometimes, situations like this arise because the data isn't what you think it is.  I would suggest that you run the query with the basic data in other columns so you can see what is happening:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Member_Name, ' ', last_name) AS full_name, Member_Name, last_name
FROM members
ORDER BY last_name DESC, Member_Name DESC;
```

You are likely to find an anomaly in the data.  For instance, "Tony House" might be in the `Member_Name` field and the `last_name` field is blank.  Or, there might be an extra space or unprintable character in the `last_name` field.

Comment: Or maybe that the surname is `' House'` (looking at the output, it appears to me as though there is more than a single space between `'Tony'` and `'House'`).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is absolutely correct. You need the data order by lastname, so however you may structure the query it will be same output.